# Android studio - build failed '/home/node/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Suddenly I could not build my projects with Android Studio by this following error. I have attached build.gradle file and SDK installation images, I have tried several hours but I could not get solved. Please help me to solve this problem.

Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':qApp:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/node/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.qapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':payPalDemo1')
    compile project(':uberLibrary')
    compile project(':bSLibrary')
    compile project(':pullToRefresh')
    compile project(':androidmapsutils')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/cardio.jar')
    compile files('libs/UserFormValidation.jar')
}
```

SDK list
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this inside you gradle file:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 23   
..... 

    dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this lines in your dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

And in the defaultConfig, use the same **targetSdkVersion** of the **compileSdkVersion**